# Using find and aggregate on mongoDB/Mongoose to fetch data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a node.js project to display some data using charts and tables on the front end.

I have the two following queries on my route:

```
    atendimentos.find({})
        .then(atendimentos => {
            final = atendimentos.filter(atendimentos => atendimentos.status === 'F')
            testeea = atendimentos.filter(atendimentos => atendimentos.status === 'EA')
            res.render('home', {user: req.user, fin: final.length, ea: testeea.length});
            //Funciona
            console.log(final.length)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

    atendimentos.aggregate([
        { $project:
                { _id: "$month",
                    year: {$year: "$date" },
                    month: { $month: "$date"},
                    amount: 1
                }
        },
        { $group:
                { _id: { year: "$year", month: ("$month")},
                    sum: { $sum: 1}
                }
        }]).exec(function(error, items){
        if(error){return next(error);}

        console.log(items);
    });
```

**EDIT 1:**

So, the input data... I guess that I don't have any because I'm actually fetching everything from the database through my queries. The data that I expect, are the documents/object with the status F or EA which I'm rendering on my chart.

The database has around 8.5k documents, the F one returns 8041 documents and the EA returns 351, it is a simple array with the number that is returned using .length on my route. Those numbers are rendered on the chart.

Now, related to the aggregation part, I'm trying to make a table using the collection. I intend to show the number of support calls (atendimentos) per month. It's actually logging the correct data like this:

```
[ { _id: { year: 2018, month: 6 }, sum: 4005 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 7 }, sum: 43 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 5 }, sum: 3996 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 4 }, sum: 434 } ]
```

And I want to use this data to render the table on my view.

**END OF EDIT 1**

**EDIT 2**

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) =>  {

    let final;
    let testeea;

    atendimentos.find({})
        .then(atendimentos => {
            final = atendimentos.filter(atendimentos => atendimentos.status === 'F')
            testeea = atendimentos.filter(atendimentos => atendimentos.status === 'EA')

            res.render('home', {user: req.user, fin: final.length, ea: testeea.length});
            //Funciona
            console.log(final.length)
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

So, here's the route, the other part is just the aggregation query that I've tried to do and closing brackets. As you can see, I get the data and use Array.filter to filter the results fetched, using status = F or = EA.

It returns me the length of the array, so it counts the number of status with each letter. This number is rendered in the chart, because I'm sending it to the front end as fin: final.length and ea: testeea.length. No formatted data or something like that in here. It's okay this way.

Related to the aggregation part where it returns the calls per month, I want to use just the number of calls, month and year. In this part I expected the data like: `[ { _id: { year: 2018, month: 6 }, sum: 4005 }`

I wish I could fetch the data the same way as I've fetched the fin and ea, using .length to count and put it into the view.

**END OF EDIT 2**

Both are returning exactly what I need, the problem is that I can't just put the aggregation query before the find query and add items: items to the render method. I would like to know how do I do these queries to display the same that that I'm fetching on these two queries. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### MongoDB Server 3.2 and below

You need to run two aggregate queries and merge the objects in the results. This can be done in a multiple ways but can show you the Promise way and the async/await approach.

**1. Using Promises**

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, (req, res, next) =>  {
    const counts = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group': { 
            '_id': null,             
            'fin': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'F' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            },
            'ea': {
                '$sum': {
                    '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'EA' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                }
            }
        } }
    ]).exec();

    const monthly = atendimentos.aggregate([
        { '$group': { 
            '_id': { 
                'year': { '$year': '$date' },
                'month': { '$month': '$date' }
            },
            'sum': { '$sum':  1 }
        } },
        {  '$group': {
            '_id': null,
            'back': { '$push':  '$$ROOT' }
        } },
    ]).exec();

    Promise.all([ counts, monthly ]).then(([ counts, monthly ]) => {
        const statusData = counts[0];
        const monthlyData = monthly[0];

        const data = {...statusData, ...monthlyData, user: req.user};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

        res.render('home', data);
    }).catch(err => next(err));

});
```

**2. Using async/await**

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) =>  {
    try {
        const counts = await atendimentos.aggregate([
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': null,             
                'fin': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'F' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                'ea': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'EA' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                }
            } }
        ]).exec();

        const monthly = await atendimentos.aggregate([
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': { 
                    'year': { '$year': '$date' },
                    'month': { '$month': '$date' }
                },
                'sum': { '$sum':  1 }
            } },
            {  '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'back': { '$push':  '$$ROOT' }
            } },
        ]).exec();

        const statusData = counts[0];
        const monthlyData = monthly[0];

        const data = {...statusData, ...monthlyData, user: req.user};
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

        res.render('home', data);
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
});
```

---

### MongoDB Server 3.4.4 and above

The aggregation pipeline can also handle filtering, you just need to use the **[`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)** pipeline step which is capable of processing multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents.

Consider running the following pipeline:

```
atendimentos.aggregate([
    { '$facet': {
        'counts': [
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': null,             
                'fin': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'F' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                },
                'ea': {
                    '$sum': {
                        '$cond': [ { '$eq': [ '$status', 'EA' ] }, 1, 0 ]
                    }
                }
            } }
        ],
        'monthly': [
            { '$group': { 
                '_id': { 
                    'year': { '$year': '$date' },
                    'month': { '$month': '$date' }
                },
                'sum': { '$sum':  1 }
            } },
            {  '$group': {
                '_id': null,
                'items': { '$push':  '$$ROOT' }
            } },
        ]
    } },
    { '$replaceRoot': { 
        'newRoot': { 
            '$mergeObjects': { 
                '$concatArrays': ['$counts', '$monthly'] 
            } 
        } 
    } }
]).exec((err, results) => {
    const data = results[0];
    console.log(data);

    res.render('home', { user: req.user, ...data });
})
```

Comment: So all the data will be returned into this result array, right?  I'm a little bit confused because on my chart configuration I have <%= fin %> and <%= ea %> to render the data into the chart. I don't know how I can access these data with the result array, it's not clear to me.

Comment: Edited with what you asked, hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, I was hoping you would clarify on an example of the desired data that you are passing on to your view i.e. `res.render('home', data)`. You only explained the bit about returning the aggregated monthly counts but didn't specify what your final/overall expected result is, for example, are you expecting data like `{ user: "test_user", fin: 8500, ea: 8041, items: [{ _id: { year: 2018, month: 6 }, sum: 4005 },
  { _id: { year: 2018, month: 7 }, sum: 43 }, ... ] }`?

Comment: Edited, now I've put the route and explained more.

Comment: Thanks for the subsequent edit but I feel my point is getting lost somewhere; I simply want to understand the data the client expects from the server, an edit with sample JSON data that you want would have sufficed but you only showed disjointed data. Have you tried running the pipeline in the above answer and if so, did the results array conform to your expectations? If not please let me know an example of the overall expected JSON output you need to be passed on to the view.

Comment: Well, if you're talking about just copying and pasting the pipeline, it didn't work when I tried because it returns "cannot read property '0' of undefined, which is weird. About the JSON, I don't know how I can get an example, but isn't it possible to access the data like this: array[i].year, array[i].month, array[i].amount? So the JSON would look like: {year: 2018, month: 7}, sum: 43}... I can post the collection model if you think that it could help somehow.

Comment: Any suggestions of what I can do?